# What are the accepted SECURITY_PRINCIPAL formats for LDAP Authentication against Active Directory?

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to authenticate a user through LDAP against Active Directory. Following is the code snippet I use:

```
private DirContext bindAsUser(String bindPrincipal, String password) {
    Hashtable<String,String> env = new Hashtable<String,String>();
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, bindPrincipal);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, bindUrl);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

    try {
        return new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

The code for binding works if I provide:

- Down-Level Logon Name, i.e. `NetBIOSDomainName\sAMAccountName` (e.g. domain\username), or
- `userPrincipalName` (e.g. username@abc.com), or
- `distinguishedName` (e.g. CN=username,OU=xxx,DC=abc,DC=com), or
- `objectSid` (e.g. S-1-5-21-3623811015-3361044348-30300820-1013)

as the `SECURITY_PRINCIPAL`, while it failed if `sAMAccountName` (e.g. username) was used (I guess only the names which are unique within the forest are valid).

So what are the accepted patterns for `SECURITY_PRINCIPAL`? I searched a few similar questions, but none provide reference to official AD/LDAP documents. Or is it a configuration which I could lookup somewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [MS-ADTS: Active Directory Technical Specification], the official doc for AD I guess.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223499.aspx

Section "5.1.1.1.1 Simple Authentication" lists all the name forms supported by simple authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need check LDAP Principal Template. It specifies the principal authentication template required by your LDAP server. The principal authentication template is the format in which the authentication information for the security principal (the person who is logging in) must be passed to the LDAP server. The default value is ${email}, which is the format required by Microsoft Active Directory. Other LDAP servers require different authentication templates. Check with your network administrator to learn more about your LDAP server.